# How to make a medium.com like image uploader in a ruby on rails?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, upload, image-uploading

favoriteSure there is the medium-editor plugin and his jquery image uploader, but I can't get them to work on ruby on rails. Work as in I don't know which path I have to point the javascript uploader to in order for it to upload the image and send me the file address back so it can be shown inline as it is shown in medium.com

Does any one have any other alternative that works for rails or did anyone meet success in doing it?

Not to remote servers like s3, upload on a local server

An exemple : http://orthes.github.io/medium-editor-insert-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, if it's still relevant, but one of users just posted his solution here: https://github.com/orthes/medium-editor-insert-plugin/issues/27#issuecomment-43472916